# Git fetch origin - fatal bad object

Tags: git

Here's the commandline:

```
git fetch origin 6301fc06a6d2f2171ca817f7d17eecb0889fcf23 :refs/remotes/origin/current_commit

fatal: bad object 6301fc06a6d2f2171ca817f7d17eecb0889fcf23

error: ssh://MyRepo did not send all necessary objects
```

Any idea ? thx.

Comment: This sha1 is not related to any branch.

Answer (score 2):

'sha1' is related with git objetcs.

[SHA1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) is just a  cryptographic hash function.

You should use the SHA1 code instead of 'sha1' in your command

Comment: this sha 1 has for value: 6301fc06a6d2f2171ca817f7d17eecb0889fcf23
Caps or not won't change anything.